# GoogleTagManager v5 iOS set up problems

Tags: ios, swift, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to implement `GTM +  Firebase` in my iOS application but I'm not sure if it's correctly initialized or not. At the moment I'm using `GTM v5.0.8`, the JSON file has been added to the project directory and firebase is sending events. 
I can see that events are tagged with "`app+gtm`" but I don't have any clue why the info

**GoogleTagManager** info: Loading container: `GTM-XXXX`
`GoogleTagManager` info: Attempting to load saved version of container `GTM-XXXX`

don't appear in my console. If I remove the container the
`GoogleTagManager` **warning**:

> GoogleTagManager warning: No default container found. Container needs to be added to a container folder and added to the target.

correctly appears in my console. So I suspect that everything is working but without the logging information I'm not 100% sure of this.

Comment: If you arrived here for the "No default container found.[...]" warning as I did at first, have a look on my Q&A here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807340/googletagmanager-warning-no-default-container-found-container-needs-to-be-adde I hope it will help some of you :)

Answer (score 1):

i got the loading container info only in simulator debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to enable the console debug of Firebase ?

> You can enable verbose logging as follows:
>
> In Xcode, select Product > Scheme > Edit scheme...
>
> - Select Run from the left menu.
> - Select the Arguments tab.
> - In the Arguments Passed On Launch section, add -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled.

Found this in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/events#view_events_in_the_xcode_debug_console).