# GoogleTagManager warning: No default container found. Container needs to be added to a container folder and added to the target

Tags: ios, firebase, google-tag-manager

While trying to implement Google Tag Manager v5 in my Swift app, I faced the following warning, which caused me some troubles :

> GoogleTagManager warning: No default container found. Container needs to be added to a container folder and added to the target.

It took me more time than it should have, and since the answer for my problem was pretty hard to find and was not on SO, I decided to create this Q&A, in case some people would be in the same situation as mine !

Comment: Hey, can you kindly answer the following questions if you have idea.. Thanks in anticipation 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/43761571/4297260

Comment: @FayzaNawaz : I'm looking for your issue and answer your question asap.

Comment: I totally agree with the N3bie answer above. However, I had to search how to do some of the things in his post, so I've listed them here for those who don't know how to do these steps. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346247/xcode-project-navigator-difference-between-yellow-folder-and-blue-folder) helped me see how to create a blue folder and explain the difference between a blue and yellow folder in Xcode And this support [article](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106997?hl=en) contains instructions on how to export your container, which is a json file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, make sure you're using the correct GTM container type : it should be displayed as **iOS**, not as **iOS (legacy)** here : https://tagmanager.google.com/?hl=en#/home

Then, create a folder named **container** in your project, and download your actual container in it.
[image: Download the container into a container folder in your project]

Now, you just have to import the folder you just created :

- right click into Xcode file tree
- "Add files to 'MyProject'"
- click the container **folder**
- then the options button

  - select create folder reference
  - select also copy items if needed
  - select your targets
- click the add button.

[image: Add files options view]

Everything should work as expected now ! In order to be sure you made things right, the container folder should appear as a **blue** folder in your Xcode file tree, not as a **yellow** one.

Comment: After struggle of multiple hours, i found your answer.. It's a life savior. Thank you..

Comment: @n3wbie How to do this in phonegap build can u please explain

Comment: @VenkaTeshuser5397700 Unfortunately, I never used phonegap, and I'm not able to help for this. Maybe you should create a new thread to ask this question ?

Comment: Does it have to be named GTM-XXXX.json? Will this still work if I call it gtm-config-ios.json ? I'm assuming there's no connection between the container that's configured in the backend and the actual filename of the configuration file. I tried renaming it but it looks like nothing is getting logged

Comment: the best answer you can find! after many hours trying to build, I finally found this. thanks

Comment: Thanks for this, I've followed the steps and everything seems to be set up as expected. How do we verify that Google Tag Manager has been set up correctly ? I don't see any logs in the Xcode console that mention Google Tag Manager so how were you able to verify ?